# In Python, how to make "class" (when passed as a parameter) work the same as "class.attribute"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So, I am currently making a custom Tkinter module/API mainly just so I can get a better understanding of Tkinter, but I've run into a problem. Suppose I have the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

Class Window(object):  # Equivalent of Tkinters Tk() in my module
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        ...


Class Label(object):  # Equivalent of Tkinters label widget in my module
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="Hello world!")
        ...
```

How can I make it so when I'm creating a label widget, I may do

```
master = Window()
label = Label(master)
```

Instead of having to do

```
master = Window()
label = Label(master.root)
```

I know I can inherit `tk.Tk` into my window class, but I'm just curious if there's a different way of doing it. I've done some research and it seems it may have something to do with one of the built-in methods with the leading and trailing double underscores (not sure what they're called), but I don't know what most of those do.

P.S. Sorry for bad title, wasn't sure how to describe it in a short sentence :P

Comment: Why do you not want to inherit from `Tk`? This is precisely what inheritance is for.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's what I ended up doing, was just curious if there was another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
self.label = tk.Label(master.root, text="Hello world!")
```

But as Brian and Paul said, inherit from tk.Tk is the best thing to do.